# How do the environments of a standard Terminal command-line and a bash script differ?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripts

I know there is something different about the environment of the Terminal command-line and the environment in a bash script, but I don't know what that difference is...

Here is the example which finally led me to ask this quesiton; it may flush out some of the differences.

I am trying to strip leading '0's from a number, with this command.

- `var="000123"; var="${var##+(0)}" ; echo $var`

When I run this command from the Terminal's command-line, I get:  **`123`**

However, when I run it from within a script, it doesn't work; I get:  **`000123`**

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04, and tried all the following with the sam results:

- GNOME Terminal 2.30.2
- Konsole 2.4.5
- #!/bin/bash
- #!/bin/sh

My bash version 4 1 5 1 release i486-pc-linux-gnu (in terminals and scripts)

'shopt' differences between CLI and Script:

```
    CLI   Script  
    on     off    checkwinsize    
    on     off    expand_aliases  
    on     off    extglob         
    on     off    histappend      
    off    on     hostcomplete
```

---

What is causing this difference?

Even if some upgrade will make it work in scripts...
I am trying to find out the **what** and **why**, 
so in future, I'll know what to look out for.

---

Here are 3 **bash** ways to strip leading '0's. (I knew only one when I first asked this queston)

```
var=0001230; var="$[10#$var]";           echo $var   # fastest= 1.00  integers only
var=0001230; var="${var##+(0)}";         echo $var   # slower x 1.25  works with strings, but requires shopt -s extglob
var=0001230; var="${var#${var%%[!0]*}}"; echo $var   # slower x 1.61  works with strings
```

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of var="${var##+(0)} ? I assume it's some shell formatting mechanism but could find any details about it.

Comment: It strips leading, (**only leading**) strings.. like "^\\(abc\\)\+" in sed/grep... I went a-hunting the other day... and after much rummaging and scrummaging, I found this... and it suited my needs perfectly... (As I recall, there was some mention of it being new, and you would neeed "such-and-such".. I tried it (in the terminal, and it worked, so I didn't pay any special attention to it until now, when I used it in a script...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question cannot be answered quite generally. Some comments though. On my version of bash (3.1.17(1)-release), your command doesn't have the desired output even when run from the command line; the same with zsh. So presumably something is fishy about your command. I don't know what "##+(0)" is suppoed to accomplish, but "#0" succeeds in removing one leading zero. [This](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2005/12/11/stripping-leading-zeros-with-bash/) show a way to remove arbitrary numbers of zeros.

If there really is a difference between the behavior on the command line and from a script, then most likely the script uses a different interpreter (different bash version, bash instead of zsh) or different shell options (try running `shopt`). The latter difference might be the result of your interactive shell sourcing `$HOME/.bashrc` and `$HOME/.profile` whereas scripts generally don't. That shouldn't affect environment variables, as they're inherited if exported, but it should affect shell options, which need to be set in every shell.

Comment: loevborg. I have added comment below my question about the use of ##+(0)... and about my current bash version.

Comment: I've added more system specs to the body of the question

Comment: loevborg, You were right on target with your reference to `shopt` ... Everything else seems to be the same, and there are differences in my *shopt* settings, so I tried to re-find the web page where I first encountered this command...  Actually it was much easier to find this time :)... He mentions that `extglob` must be `on`... mine is `on` for the CLI, but `off` for scripts! .... When I precede the command with *shopt -s extglob*, the commands works fine!... so Thanks for that! .... (I don't know how to make this permanent setting, but I should be able to work it out (I hope :)

Comment: PS. I just now found a neat and simple method to remove leading '0's which doesn't require  `extglob`... its: `var="000123000"; echo "$[10#$var]"` It uses numeric-base conversion, so it only works for '0's.. the other method is *string*-based

Comment: Don't use `$[...]`. It's a deprecated syntax for math in bash, and it will disappear at some point. Use `$((...))` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you're using the same shell in your script and in your terminal, the main difference is that `~/.bashrc` is read by interactive shells but not by script-interpreting shells. The reason is that scripts are usually meant to be somewhat portable, and for that you don't want to depend on the user's shell customizations.

Many things in typical `.bashrc` files only apply to the command line anyway (prompt settings, key bindings). Some, like function definitions, make sense in scripts as well; typically you'd put them into a separate file and source it both from `~/.bashrc` and scripts. Sometimes you want some shell options for interactive use but not in scripts, because they lead to shorter (good on the command line) but more cryptic or less portable (bad in scripts) code. There are a few things that bash does differently, e.g. history expansion (`!!`, etc.) is on by default only in interactive shells.

Here you're using the `+(…)` construct, which is a ksh extended globbing pattern. Bash doesn't enable them by default (for backward compatibility) but you can turn them on with `shopt -s extglob`. Apparently you have this in your `~/.bashrc`.

You can put `shopt -s extglob` in your script, or use a portable way of truncating leading `0`s from a variable such as

```
var=${var#${var%%[!0]*}}
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles, it's a great amswer and I like this "new" way to strip lead '0's... but I'm a bit OD'd on it at the moment (it, and another couple of questions) .. I'll come back to it when I've recharged my batteries..... I've added 3 "strip-lead-0s" methods as a footnote to my question.. They may be handy for someone...it took me long enough to find them! :)

Comment: In Ubuntu, interactive bash shells have extended globbing turned on by default because the default user `.bashrc` file (viewable as `/etc/skel/.bashrc`) sources `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, which [contains `shopt -s extglob progcomp`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634397/where-is-bashs-shopt-extglob-turned-on-for-my-interactive-shell).