# Wild card expansion that works on command line but not in a bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I read that I must put the command

```
shopt -s extglob
```

in `.bashrc` in order to use `!(XYZ)` as a wild card expansion for everything in the current directory except XYZ. Testing indicated that

```
cp -aruv !(XYZ) $target
```

indeed copied everything from the current directory to $target except sub directory XYZ. Then I included the cp statement in a bash script. The script died at the cp statement with error message

```
cp: invalid option --'h'
```

which I cannot explain. I added the shopt command to my script and got the same result.

I found this wild card expansion in "Your UNIX" by Das  with the comment to add the shopt statement to .bashrc. I do not find `shopt` in either man or info.

Any help would be appreciated to get the correct wild card expansion in a bash script statement and on where to find information on the shopt command.

There have been questions about my script that I tried to answer but did so in the wrong place. There are portions of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
if shopt -s extglob
then
    echo "shopt was successful"
else
    echo "shopt was not successful"
    exit -1
fi
```

Following these statements is a loop in which target and source are set and tested to insure that they point to directories. Then the code that fails

```
cd $source
cp -aruv !(XYZ) $target
```

Again I point out that if I set target and source from the command line and then

```
cd $source
cp -aruv !(XYZ) $target
```

the copy works as I expect. I can do this other ways but would like to understand why this does not work in my script and how to fix it.

Comment: So where is the script you speak of?

Comment: This would occur in the (unlikely) event that your directory contains a file called '-h'.

Comment: Please include the relevant lines from your script. We can't help you much without them. You'll find `shopt` under `help` since it is a shell builtin (`help shopt`).

Comment: ...and the first line is relevant too, you may be even be running bash.  e.g. #!/bin/sh is really running dash.

Comment: My script is listed with line numbers.

Comment: 1 #!/bin/bash
 2 if shopt -s extglob
 3 then
 4     echo "shopt was successful"
 5 else
 6     echo "shopt was not successful"
 7     exit -1
 8 fi

Comment: Then later    41         cp -aruv !(XYZ) $target ;;

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the default Ubuntu `~/.bashrc` file, then extended globbing is enabled by default<sup>1</sup> **for interactive shells** - which is why it works on the command line.

Inside a script however, you will need to enable it with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

`shopt` is documented in `man bash` under the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section, or via the shell's online help

```
help shopt
```

---

<sup>1</sup> albeit rather opaquely, via bash completions. See for example [Where is bash's “shopt extglob” turned on for my interactive shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634397/where-is-bashs-shopt-extglob-turned-on-for-my-interactive-shell)

Comment: I put the shopt comaand as the second line of my script. The same error occurs.