# ls with wildcard and brackets working in console but not in a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

**Command**:

```sh
ls /etc/pve/lxc/*([0-9]).conf
```

**Working in console**:

- Result: file found !

```
/etc/pve/lxc/107.conf
```

**but not in script**:

- #!/bin/bash
- Result: ERROR

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
ls /etc/pve/lxc/*([0-9]).conf
```

**Then I masked the brackets in the script**:

```sh
ls /etc/pve/lxc/*\([0-9]\).conf
```

- Result: No file found

```
ls: cannot access '/etc/pve/lxc/*([0-9]).conf': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 15):

The expression `*([0-9]).conf` is a KSH-style *extended glob*. The feature is enabled by default for interactive bash shells, but to use it in a bash script it must be enabled explicitly using

```
shopt -s extglob
```

See also [Wild card expansion that works on command line but not in a bash script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054597/wild-card-expansion-that-works-on-command-line-but-not-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: Thx. That was the solution!

Answer (score 7):

The information you do not provide is which command interpreter is used in the script. This is indicated by the shebang, i.e. the first line (eg. `#/bin/sh`).

In Ubuntu, the console by default runs bash as the interactive shell. If your script uses another command interpreter, e.g. /bin/sh, syntax specific to bash will not work.